# Unity - following finger only works for one direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made some code that should make my player move into the direction of the finger:

```c#
if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    Vector2 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y, 0));

    if (pos.x < rb.position.x)
    {
        movehorizontal = -1;
    }
    if(pos.x > rb.position.x)
    {
        movehorizontal = 1;
    }

    if (pos.y < rb.position.z)
    {
        movevertical = -1;
    }
    if(pos.y > rb.position.z)
    {
        movevertical = 1;
    }
}

Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movehorizontal, 0.00f, movevertical)*speed;
```

It's a 3D game, with a top-view, so my player starts at 0,0,0 and only moves along the x and z axis. My camera is positionated on 0,10,3. The following works on the x axis, so when my finger touches on the right side it goes to the right, if on the left to the left, but no matter where I touch it, it will only move to the front and not to the bottom of my screen.

I tried debugging, but the [instructions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html) werent working at the time.

Comment: You could/should instead simply use [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) or [Vector2.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html)

Comment: You should use `camelCase` instead of `typinglikethisthatsreallyhardtoreaed`. Also, you should use more `else if` statements because `pos.x` can't be `< rb.position.x` and `> rb.position.x`, if it is the first, it shouldn't check again for the second, because that will always be false

Answer (score 1):

screentoWorldPoint should be stored as a vector3. also since the camera is 10 units away from your plane the last parameter should be 10.

edit, that will only work for a cam pointing straight down. this code should work regardless of the camera angle.

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y, 1f));

Vector3 pointDelta = pos - Camera.main.transform.position;
float multiplier = -Camera.main.transform.position.y / pointDelta.y;
pos = Camera.main.transform.position + pointDelta * multiplier;
```

finally these lines should compare the z values to each other

```
 if (pos.z < rb.position.z)

 if(pos.z > rb.position.z)
```

make those changes and let us know if any other problems still exist

Comment: if it is backwards switch your 1 and -1 for movehorizontal or movevertical, whichever axis is wrong